# Prevent padding from deforming div

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of text to put in a little `<div>` box so I don't have to much space and the size is very precise.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="myBox">Box</div>

<style>

    .myBox{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:6px;
    }

</style>
```

**I don't want my padding to deform my box.**

**I can't change the width and height proprety.**

Comment: this has nothing to do with php...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following property:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This will change `box-sizing` from the default `content-box`, whose width is based solely on content. `border-box`'s width and height include content, `padding`, and border (but not `margin`) sizes.